# How do I skin a Java JTree to look like it was meant for an xml document?

Tags: java, xml, jtree

I have a JTree and the default look-and-feel of the icons and such look like it's meant for a file structure (with folder and document icons).

I'm wondering how I can override the look-and-feel programmatically, or via a library (Is there an XML JTree library?).

Comment: Have you looked at any [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20tree%20icon)?

Comment: I don't know if changing the look and feel is necessary for altering just the JTree. You can easily alter the images (the file icon in your case) to be whatever you like. FE, `UIManager.put("Tree.leafIcon", vectorIcon);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a very good example explained [here](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2007/07/22/showing-the-file-system-as-a-swing-jtree.html) along with source code.
It's via `getTreeCellRendererComponent()` which you can further customize.
It's also optimized for performance.